# How to setup a cron tab to restart a game server using screen

Tags: server, bash, cron, games, steam

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I have been trying to setup a scheduled restart every 2 days at 4 AM for my Unturned Server.

This is my crontab:

```
* */3 * * * root/.steam/steamcmd/Unturned1 ; screen -XS Unturned1 quit; /usr/bin/screen -dmS Unturned1 ; ./ServerHelper.sh +InternetServer/Unturned1
```

The "*/3" is just to test every 3 minutes, the crontab successfully ends the screen and starts a new one, but when it's supposed to execute the shell to start the server it just glitches and stays like this:

[image: screen when it's supposed to start the shell]

Comment: Don't. Create a service unit (and a timer if you want). Takes about 10m to create and you can then stop/start/restart the unit and you can add that to cron. Far more versatile.

Comment: you did not install steam in root/ did you? :P Very  bad if you did ;) use /opt/  or /home/$USER/

Comment: i tried installing it using linuxgsm through an user but when i uploaded some files to the server i ran into some permission issues that i wasnt able to fix, so i decided to just install it on root instead of a user, anyways, i have taken a look at systemd and i would want to know how do i add a .service file to the crontab? also, is there any way to execute a command in the server console to warn players before server is restarted?

Comment: Is there a reason for posting a blank screen.